# Change button style radio group in Android

Tags: android

I would like to change the default button button style of Android radio buttons to suit my theme. How could I achieve that?

[image: Android prototype]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a selector drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/radio_selected"  android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/radio_normal" />

</selector>
```

then in your xml of the radio button
    android:button="@drawable/(your drawable name)"

example:

```
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radio_button_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:button="@drawable/your_drawable_name"
    android:text="your_text" />
```

Answer (score 2):

See [Adding custom radio buttons in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19163628/adding-custom-radio-buttons-in-android). Hope this helps you.