# How can I have a line of ToggleButtons so that just one of them can be selected?

Tags: android, xml, radio-button, row, togglebutton

I want to have a row of squared shaped buttons. It should act like radio buttons so that only one can be selected at a time. But it should seem like ToggleButtons. Which is having a square shape that contains the text and when the user clicks it toggles.

How can I do this? Can anyone give me a sample? I'm willing to do it in XML not
programmatically.

I want it to look like this with texts inside
[image: I want it to look like this with texts inside]

EDIT: A better way to ask this question:
How can I customize a RadioButon group in a way that they look like ordinary Buttons?

Comment: I suppose the answer can be found here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19163628/adding-custom-radio-buttons-in-android

Comment: Did you already find the right answer for your question?

Comment: I guess so. I'm new to Android and I'm a bit slow. So far I have found nothing wrong with the above link while testing it.

Comment: The above link in my comment is the correct answer. I checked everything and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Ok, I am going to delete my answer.