# Customizing radiobuttons in android

Tags: android, android-radiogroup, android-radiobutton

### [I am extending a question i asked few time back in stackoverflow - Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19163628/1083093)

---

[As seen in the answer - Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19163987/1083093)  I get my required output

**I get a output as**:

[image]

---

### What i am trying to do::

*Keeping all other functionality i want to show an `image` in place of `Button` text*

---

**How can i achieve this** !

Comment: You could not set the text AND set  `android:button="@drawable/your_picture"` instead of `android:button="@android:color/transparent"`

Comment: @  Frank N. Stein .... Where should i place that attribute in the drawables ? .... because i cannot put it in button since i am already reffering the drawables ... can you show a sample

Comment: you can set image as a background inside button.

Comment: I made my comment an answer, for more clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could not set the text AND set  `android:button="@drawable/some_drawable"` **instead of** `android:button="@android:color/transparent"`, as in:

```
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radio0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/yourbuttonbackground"
    android:button="@drawable/some_drawable"
    android:checked="true"
/>
```

You have only 3 ways to set drawables in a RadioButton:

- background (you need this for the "border layer-list")
- button (recommended)
- compound drawable/s (less recommended, since the positions are fixed at the sides, but you might want to experiment)