# Can I set default button is clicked or selected in android?

Tags: android

I want to do something like when I start the activity, "button A" is clicked ( or selected) as default , a String will be shown immediately in the textview. And there is another Button, "button B". When I click on it, "button A" isSelected  set to be false and "button B" isSelected set to be true, show required "button b" text.

I am already done the button change text when isSelected(), I just cannot set one of it as default "clicked" or "selected", can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried with `myButton.performClick`?

Comment: thanks for helping but not work for me :p

Comment: bro, can I put performClick() right after I declare it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
mButton.setSelected(true);
```

Comment: ya, I have set one of the button as true and the others as false when I " click" it. I want to do is set one of it is true as default before i clicked it or when i enter the activity.

Comment: Then you could put 'mButton.setSelected(true)' in your 'onCreate()' where your activity is created.

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 2):

I consider you can use [RadioGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html) for this case. More details [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html)

Comment: I am using butten item state as i have to handle color changing, any solution for it?

Comment: Have you tried [ColorStateList](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html) and checked state?

Comment: Yes, I can change the text and color when I clicked it, but not default selected.

Comment: Actually I want to do the same thing like RadioGroup, but I cant when i make a group of customerize button. Thanks for the extensive help

Comment: I think what you are looking for is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19163628/adding-custom-radio-buttons-in-android)

Comment: Appreciate for ur greatly help, but i think i got the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can create a OnClick function of that button, and call it in onCreate().