# How can I change radio button to contain text and look like a selectable button?

Tags: android

How can I get selectable view on my gridview like this
[image: Selectable]

I have checked some of the suggestions on a few questions but I still am not able to make it work using Buttons. If it is possible with this I still can use it though most suggestions state that you can change the radio button but none shows how. I need mine with text or color or both according to the category. Only one view in the grid can be selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may consider customising your radio button by changing the images associated with it.refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19163628/adding-custom-radio-buttons-in-android)