# Android. ImageView as RadioButton

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview, android-radiogroup, android-radiobutton

I want some `ImageViews` to work as `RadioButtons`. But I don't want the mini-button of a `RadioButton` to select it; I want this mini-button to disappear, and the ImageView to be the entire button. Thus, a solution like the following one is not good.

```
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/myId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/myIcon"/>
```

Is there a widget or something which I can use to use `ImageViews` as `RadioButtons`, or should I program myself all the logic of the buttons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will suggest to create your custom radio button. check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19163987/1186689) of *Evan Bashir*

Answer (score 2):

you can try with **button** attribute like bellow.

```
<RadioButton
android:id="@+id/myId"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:button="@drawable/myIcon"/>
```

or through grammatically.

```
myRadioButton.setButtonDrawable(resourceId or Drawable);
```

and you can change the images while selecting the RB through the following xml file...save this file in drawable folder and call it in the `button` attribute or grammatically .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/star_down" />
<item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/star" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set the image in the `android:background` of the RadioButton's XML declaration. 
Also set the `android:button` to transparent: `android:button="@android:color/transparent"`

If you want to have different states - create a selector with different images for the two states.