# Right to Left Custom Radio Buttons

Tags: android, xamarin, radio-button

I saw this link: [Adding custom radio buttons in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19163628/adding-custom-radio-buttons-in-android).

It is better than this picture (my design) but it is not right to left:

[image]

How can I put the text of radio button in left side of the button in that link?
With thanks

EDITED:
I want this output but right to left

[image]

EDITED: 
It is possible that the output looks like below figure?

[image]

Comment: Just so we're all clear, I think this is what you're looking for, right?  https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/8008527/21685683/764a7074-d330-11e6-9909-efd968874aaa.png

Comment: OK and the "Radiobutton1" and "Radiobutton2" and "Radiobutton3" are the left side of buttons, first buttons and then text.

Comment: I want the shape of the first figure with the shape of buttons of the second figure. The buttons of the first figure is not nice.

Comment: The look/shape of the buttons is a separate question altogether.  You should make another question for customizing the `appearance` of the radio buttons themselves.  We were all addressing your right to left situation :)

Comment: I've updated my sample to match your request.

Comment: Could you please review all of the answers and comments, were you able to find a solution? :)

Answer (score 0):

you can set `android:button="@null"` ans then with `android:drawable(position)` define direction of drawable for RadioButton to `left, right, top and bottom` like below :

```
    <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbYes"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
            android:text="RadioButton Text" />
```

---

**Edit 1 :**

as @Mubashar_Javed said`RadioGroup` for multi `RadioButton`.

or for one `RadioButton` just add `RadioButton` inside an view fore example "LinearLayout" in this form :

```
             <LinearLayout
                android:gravity="center|right"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                 <RadioButton
                   android:id="@+id/rbName"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:button="@null"
                   android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
                   android:text="RadioButton Text" />
           </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you. I edited my post. EDITED: I want this output but right to left.

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:gravity="right"` in each of your `RadioButton` as given bellow

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radios"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/first"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawablePadding="30dp"
        android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
        android:text="first"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textSize="20dip" 
        android:gravity="right"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/second"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/Black"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawablePadding="30dp"
        android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
        android:text="second"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:textSize="20dp"
         android:gravity="right"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/third"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/Maroon"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawablePadding="30dp"
        android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
        android:text="third"
        android:textColor="@color/Vanilla"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:gravity="right" />
</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: Thank you. I edited my post. EDITED: I want this output but right to left.

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT:** Here is a new version with proper RTL appearance.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:measureWithLargestChild="false"
    android:gravity="left">

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radios"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/Radiobutton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="Radiobutton 1"
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:checked="true"
            />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/Radiobutton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="Radiobutton 2"
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/Radiobutton3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="Radiobutton 3"
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/Radiobutton4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="Radiobutton 4"
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            />

    </RadioGroup>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/myButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: EDITED: It is possible that the output looks like below figure?

Comment: @user2111639 is this what you wanted?

Comment: If you looking for a version where the radio buttons are on the left side of the labels, check my EDIT history on this post