# Dynamic update of Listview on click of child

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

[image]

I populated a list of questions and answers with ListView.
Each question has 6 options(single selection); if I select any option, the previously selected option should be invalidated.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View views = convertView;
            views = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_question_list, null);
            holder = new ViewHolders();
        holder.titleQuestion = (TextView)views.findViewById(R.id.tv_quetion_label);
        holder.c_option1 = (TextView)views.findViewById(R.id.question);

        holder.ibOption1= (ImageButton)views.findViewById(R.id.ibOption1);
        holder.ibOption2= (ImageButton)views.findViewById(R.id.ibOption2);
        holder.ibOption3= (ImageButton)views.findViewById(R.id.ibOption3);
        holder.ibOption4 = (ImageButton)views.findViewById(R.id.ibOption4);
        holder.ibOption5 = (ImageButton)views.findViewById(R.id.ibOption5);
        holder.ibOption6 = (ImageButton)views.findViewById(R.id.ibOption6);

  holder.ibOption6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               // Need to select current selection and invalide previous selection.
// For current selection
 ((ImageButton) view).setSelected(type);
            }
        });
return views;
}
```

How to get the views of the other options?

Comment: Why not using [RadioButtons](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html)?

Comment: which kind of adapter you used?

Comment: Am using BaseAdapter @imankazemayni

Comment: these is custom images @YoniGross

Comment: you should set a int  arraylist or array in yor adapter. size of array must be same with your number of questions. after each click by user, you should set answer in proper position of array. and you should set current answer using read answer of each row in array

Comment: @imankazemayni , Am not able to clear previous selected option

Comment: You can use custom images in RadioButton as well. [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19163987/3942452)

Answer (score 0):

the simplest and better solution is to use Radio Group in your `row_question_list` with six radio buttons inside. You can further change orientation of parent radio group to `horizontal` to get above view. And can eventually get the selected radio button.

```
<RadioGroup>
   <RadioButton>
   <RadioButton>
   <RadioButton>
   <RadioButton>
   <RadioButton>
   <RadioButton>
</RadioGroup>
```

Further you can customize there backgrounds and set questions texts with them.

for the above view, you can make a drawable with images for `state_selected = true` and `state_selected = false` after every click on each button you can change button states of all the rest of buttons in the view or even you can change backgrounds.

```
holder.ibOption6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               holder.ibOption1.setBackgroundResource(your background);
               holder.ibOption2.setBackgroundResource(your background);
               holder.ibOption3.setBackgroundResource(your background);
               holder.ibOption4.setBackgroundResource(your background);
               holder.ibOption5.setBackgroundResource(your background);
            }
        });
```

and you will have to set this for all the buttons. or you can try `notifyDataSetChanged();.`

Comment: Thanks..Is there any possibility with ImageButtons like above code?

Comment: am doing same for each option there is drawable image when click on image changing state_selected true or false, but am not able to change previous selected option

Comment: how are you setting images first time?

Comment: Using ImageButton src with drawable file

Comment: No..control on only view which we selected others are not working

Comment: you have to setonClickListener for all the buttons and in onClick change backgrounds of rest of the buttons.

Comment: Yes am doing for all button...when click on any button am able to control view of that button, but previous selected view not able to change

Comment: simply add `notifyDataSetChanged()` in end of each `onClick()`