# Android Radio Button background overlapping the default circle

Tags: android, radio-button

I have a radio button in my app with a custom shape set as its background.Now I see 2 circles,,default and the custom.I tried to use **android:button=@null**.It removes entire background.Is there any other way to remove the deafault radiobutton circle.Below is my Xml file.

Radiobutton.xml:

```
RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleX="0.3"
    android:scaleY="0.3"
    android:button="@android:color/transparent"
     android:background="@drawable/radio_selector"
    android:id="@+id/radio1"/>
```

radio_selector.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/radio_check"
        android:state_checked="true" />
    <item
        android:state_checked="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/radio_uncheck"
        >

    </item>
</selector>
```

radio_uncheck.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid
        android:color="#ffffff"></solid>
    <stroke
        android:color="#bb2b67"
        android:width="2dp"></stroke>
</shape>
```

radio_check.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid
        android:color="#bb2b67">
    </solid>
</shape>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19163987/4168607

Comment: Still Not working ....

Comment: Whats not working ? i do not see any `selector` in your code . Please edit the question with complete code .

Comment: I just created selector and tried it.Did not work.I will edit it..

Comment: Edited the question now

Comment: just set the selector file in button instead of Background. like this
android:button="@drawable/radio_selector"

Comment: Tried it before.still didnt work

Answer (score 0):

I used the below solution when I got stuck with this type of issue :-

```
<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleX="0.3"
    android:scaleY="0.3"
    android:button="@drawable/radio_uncheck"
    android:id="@+id/radio1"/>
```