# Android: Scale background image of RadioButton or another way to make a RadioButton an Image

Tags: java, android, scale, android-imagebutton, android-radiobutton

I'm making an app that is related to a card game and as such has many images of cards appear throughout the app. In one section I need the user to select one of four cards, with only one selection ever being possible and I want to have the card to change color slightly after being clicked to show that it is the currently selected one.

For the bulk of this task a RadioGroup with RadioButtons makes perfect sense since the functionality for having a checked/unchecked state and unselecting all other options when a new one is picked is built in; however, the issue is that I want the buttons to be the cards themselves and therefore an image with no text whatsoever.

At first this post looked promising: [Adding custom radio buttons in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19163628/adding-custom-radio-buttons-in-android)

My use of this strategy:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label_seatGod"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/ex2"
        android:textColor="@color/font_condition_labels"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_gen_label_size"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="8" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:button="@drawable/power_aphrodite"
            android:checked="false"
            android:text="@null" />
    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

which resulted in:
[image: Radio button with background image]

This is almost perfect. No text and the entire region of the clickable button space is composed of the image I want, EXCEPT that as you can see the image is not scaled at all and is cropped on the edges. Above the RadioButton you can see a LinearLayout with 4 ImageButtons that demonstrate exactly how I want the RadioButton/card image to appear (ignore the grey for now I haven't finished padding the views).

Essentially, I want a RadioButton that functions normally but looks exactly like one of the four ImageButtons in the top section. Ideally **scaleType="fitCenter"** would be the fix since it is what I am using in the example ImageButtons, but you cannot apply that attribute to the button drawable of a RadioButton or its background directly.

So how can I get the image to scale and not be cropped without resorting to some performance tanking layout jurry rigging or creating an entirely new RadioButton class?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there an option you can use vector drawable or different assets per dpi?

Comment: can you try hardcoding the width and height of your buttons according to your card so that it is not square?

Comment: @deathangel908 - I'll consider that but I'd like to avoid that for something this simple, especially considering that there exists such a simple way to so this with ImageView. There has to be a way to use similar functionality with an image in something else. Kinda silly that scaleType isn't an attribute for most image uses.

Comment: @Suhaib Roomy - That just changes which portion is cropped, doesn't apply scaling at all.

Comment: did you maintain the aspectRatio according to the image?

Comment: Check via [layout inspector](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector) if radio button is a complex element, and if there's an imageview inside. Also grep source of rafiobutton for  `button` attribute and check how's it set

Comment: @deathangel908 My first time using the inspector but it does not seem like it has anything under it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try adding this to your `RadioButton` in the `xml`:

```
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

Comment: As I said in the question RadioButton doesn't have that attribute unlike ImageButton.