# How can I use a FontAwesome icon as a RadioButton button

Tags: android, radio-button, font-awesome

I want to use an icon from FontAwesome as the button for a RadioButton. I want to use something like this as the icon when the RadioButton is selected: https://fontawesome.com/icons/check-circle?style=solid and then default to the regular unselected image when the RadioButton is not selected. Is this possible?

I have taken a look at setting the `button` attribute of the RadioButton, but this does not appear to work. The RadioButton expects a drawable image, not a string value. This is where I am stuck, since the FontAwesome icons are actually treated as strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the icon as svg. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19163987/10327883), you can see how to customize a RadioButton.

[Downloading FontAwesome icons as SVG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UV35p.png)

Answer (score 0):

Hello @h_k one alternative way is there to achieve the solution for that you have to take one image view with radio button and you have to just maintain the visibility according to the condition of the visibility of control.
When User click on Radio button then display image view and hide radio button
Bit it's not the correct solution ;)