# There is no change in style when click on or off on Radiobutton

Tags: android, radio-button, selector, drawable

I want to make style RadioButton when clicking off or on using **@drawable/radio_selected** like the 2 images below.

[image: Style RadioButton when clicking is off]

[image: Style RadioButton when clicking is on]

```
<RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/radio_selected"
        tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />
```

In this drawable, I use the selector to make a condition when the radio button is on or off.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/rb_on" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/rb_off" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

**rb_on.xml**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="5dp"
    android:height="5dp"
    android:viewportWidth="19"
    android:viewportHeight="19">
  <path
      android:pathData="M9.5,9.5m-6.5,0a6.5,6.5 0,1 1,13 0a6.5,6.5 0,1 1,-13 0"
      android:strokeWidth="6"
      android:fillColor="#ffffff"
      android:strokeColor="#FF8830"/>
</vector>
```

**rb_off.xml**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="5dp"
    android:height="5dp"
    android:viewportWidth="19"
    android:viewportHeight="19">
  <path
      android:pathData="M9.5,9.5m-8.5,0a8.5,8.5 0,1 1,17 0a8.5,8.5 0,1 1,-17 0"
      android:strokeWidth="2"
      android:fillColor="#ffffff"
      android:strokeColor="#FF8830"/>
</vector>
```

But, That doesn't work. The result so like this.

[image: Radiobutton style results when off]

[image: Radiobutton style results when on]

I have added several items such as "android:state_pressed", etc but the results are the same.
How to solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the icon of `RadioButton` then you need to use `android:button`

Use this

```
android:button="@drawable/radio_selected"
```

Instead of this

```
 android:background="@drawable/radio_selected"
```

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
<RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:button="@drawable/radio_selected"
        tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />
```

Comment: Got it. It's work. 
But, I want to know. I'm read from (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19163628/adding-custom-radio-buttons-in-android) using "android: background" to set drawable selector radio button. So, when to use "android: background" or "android: button" in certain radio button cases? And what is different?

Comment: @KelvinHerwandaTandrio  the post you have shared in that question the user want change the background of radio button not the icon,

if you want to change background of `RadioButton` at that you need to use `android:background` and if you want to change the icon of `RadioButton` then you need to use `android:button`

Answer (score 0):

Use button instead of background in xml

```
android:background="@drawable/radio_selected"
```

with

```
android:button="@drawable/radio_selected"
```