# How to fix Dynamic RadioButtons Programmatically?

Tags: android, radio-button

I am try to fix RadioButton layout:

[image]

I help radioButton is fix to like this:

[image]

here is my code :

```
    ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
    ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    sv.addView(ll);

        RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[10];
        RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(this); 
        rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL); 
        for(int j=0; j<((JSONArray) value).length(); j++){
               rb[j]  = new RadioButton(this);
               rb[j].setText("" + ((JSONArray) value).getString(j));
               rb[j].setId(i + 100);
               rg.addView(rb[j]);
        }

      ll.addView(rg);
      this.setContentView(sv);
```

Comment: You shouks customize you radiobuttons - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19163628/adding-custom-radio-buttons-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A LinearLayout is made to display one item next to the other, therefore it's not the best choice here.

The easy way is a [Gridlayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout), which is specifically made to display items in a grid.

For the case that you have *lots* of Radiobuttons, you could use a [Recyclerview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) with a [GridlayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/GridLayoutManager), too, but i guess that's overkill.

You might also try a [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout) together with [Flow](https://medium.com/@tapanrgohil/constraintlayout-flow-bye-bye-to-linerlayout-78fd7fa9b679) to keep your view-hierarchy shallow and scale well on differently-wide devices.

One final word: Use xml wherever you can instead of inflating views, it makes live so much easier. (Does not apply to compose)