# Android. How to customize radio button

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, radio-button, android-view

I need a radio button that is inside radio group with text on the left, an icon after the text, and a button on the right. Here is my code:

```
 <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_phone"
                android:layoutDirection="rtl"
                android:text="@string/agreement_text"
                android:textColor="@color/blue"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
```

However, in this case, the drawable is located in front of the button, and I need it to be located after the text. If you replace it with a *drawableEnd*, then the icon will be located in front of the text, which is also incorrect for me. Please tell me how to achieve the expected result.

Expected Result:

[image]

Current result (INCORRECT for me):

[image]

Comment: Why don't you just use multiple views? I don't think `RadioButton` is built for this level of customisation.

Comment: @Henry Twist, If I use multiple views then the radio group will not work as expected.

Comment: Here is the answer! Custom Radio Button: https://youtu.be/HM6WJhwrcx4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following attributes into the RadioButton, it should work.

```
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
android:textAlignment="textStart"
android:layout_gravity="start"
```

Remember to set supportsRtl property to true in your application manifest.

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:button="@drawable/ic_icon_phone_red"
        android:text="ender"
        android:textColorLink="@color/white"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</RadioGroup>
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer, but my icon is still positioned to the right in front of the button.

Comment: Could you try with RadioGroup, like below;
 <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RadioButton
       ...
    </RadioGroup>

Comment: Yes, my RadioButton is inside RadioGroup with width="match_parent" and height="wrap_content"

Comment: Perhaps I did not explain correctly, but now I have the same result. I need the phone icon to be located next to the text, and not with the button.That is, the phone icon should be on the left immediately after the text

Comment: Is this solution solve your problem? If it doesn't solve, make a custom view. for some reference check out this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19163628/adding-custom-radio-buttons-in-android

Comment: No, I changed my question.

Comment: You can make it easily with a custom view. 
1- Set your XML 
2- Create radio click listener 
3- Create your View Class

https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/building-custom-component-with-kotlin-fc082678b080

https://proandroiddev.com/android-custom-view-level-1-67ed1c3febe1