# How can I check if at least one ToggleButton has been Checked in a row of Buttons?

Tags: java, android, togglebutton

I'm working on creating an application, which amongst other features has an integrated **GAD Test** functionality (self test to calculate and measure the user's stress level). This is how it looks:

[image: GAD Test]

It is consisted of a Table, with multiple rows of **ToggleButtons**. This is the code for 1 of the buttons, as an example:

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/row1_btn4"
    android:layout_width="200px"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/button_border"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingStart="10px"
    android:paddingEnd="10px"
    android:scaleX="0.5"
    android:scaleY="0.65"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textOff="   "
    android:textOn="✓"
    android:textSize="28sp" />
```

and this is the code to check whether a button is checked or not:

```
row1_btn4.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            gadpoints += 3;
            ((DataSite) getActivity().getApplication()).setGadPoints(gadpoints);
        } else if (!isChecked) {
            gadpoints -= 3;
            ((DataSite) getActivity().getApplication()).setGadPoints(gadpoints);
        } else {
            gadpoints += 0;
            ((DataSite) getActivity().getApplication()).setGadPoints(gadpoints);
        }
    }
});
```

Everything is working as it should, if a ToggleButton is **checked**, the user is awarded the given points. However, I would like to implement 2 things:

a) Make it so that only **1 button from each row** can be checked, and prevent the user from checking another one from the same row if he / she already checked 1

b) Check whether in a row of buttons none of them has been checked, and if so, notify the user

I cannot think of a feasible solution to this, because I will be essentially checking if a button hasn't been checked, but then again, some of them are meant to be unchecked. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage having only one entry selected per row using a `RadioGroup`. To start the `RadioGroup` with nothing selected you can call `clearCheck()` on it.

To make sure that a selection was made in all rows when they click "Submit" you can call `getCheckedRadioButtonId()` on each group/row, it will return -1 if nothing was selected.

If you want to customize what the radio buttons look like there are lots of examples of how to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19163628/adding-custom-radio-buttons-in-android).

Here is an example of what that would look like in `onCreate`:

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    List<RadioGroup> rows = Arrays.asList(
        findViewById(R.id.row1),
        findViewById(R.id.row2)
    );

    // Start out with all buttons un-checked
    for(RadioGroup row : rows) {
        row.clearCheck();
    }

    // make a list of button IDs for each row to 
    // simplify calculating the score
    List<List<Integer>> rowIds = Arrays.asList(
        Arrays.asList(R.id.row1_btn1, R.id.row1_btn2, R.id.row1_btn3, R.id.row1_btn4),
        Arrays.asList(R.id.row2_btn1, R.id.row2_btn2, R.id.row2_btn3, R.id.row2_btn4)
    );

    Button submit = findViewById(R.id.submit);

    submit.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        // check that all rows have selections
        boolean missing_values = false;
        for(RadioGroup row : rows) {
            // This will be -1 if nothing was selected
            if( row.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1 ) {
                missing_values = true;
            }
        }

        if( missing_values ) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Missing entries on some rows", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else {
            // handle the result - add up scores or whatever is needed and send the data
            // to the model
            int score = 0;
            for(int r = 0; r < rows.size(); ++r) {
                int sel = rows.get(r).getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                score += rowIds.get(r).indexOf(sel);
            }
            Toast.makeText(this, "All rows selected - score = " + score, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

and the XML that goes along with it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/row1_title"
        android:text="Row 1"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/row1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/row1"/>

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/row1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/row1_title"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/row1_btn1"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/row1_btn2"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/row1_btn3"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/row1_btn4"/>

    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/row2_title"
        android:text="Row 2"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/row2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/row2"/>

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/row2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/row2_title"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/row1">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/row2_btn1"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/row2_btn2"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/row2_btn3"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/row2_btn4"/>

    </RadioGroup>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/row2"
        />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for the time you took to explain!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using toggle buttons, use a [Radio Group](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup) for each row.
Then you can design a custom drawable for Radio Buttons to make them look like what you currently have.

**Create custom button using this**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_box"/>
<item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_check"/>
```

You can get Box and Check drawable from Resource Manager in android studio.