# Need efficient way to update view on click for category list

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout

I have a view in which I need to select one of the three categories.

Each category is a Button.

Selected category should have black background with white text while other categories should have white background with black text.

I have done it by creating button for each category and updating on each click event. **Is there any better way to do it?**

**What to do if the number of categories is not fixed?**

```
val filterBoth: Button = parentView.findViewById(R.id.filter_both)
val filterVeg: Button = parentView.findViewById(R.id.filter_veg)
val filterNonveg: Button = parentView.findViewById(R.id.filter_nonveg)

filterBoth.setOnClickListener(this)
filterVeg.setOnClickListener(this)
filterNonveg.setOnClickListener(this)

override fun onClick(view: View?) {
    filterBoth.backgroundTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(R.color.white)
    filterBoth.setTextColor(R.color.black)
    filterVeg.backgroundTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(R.color.white)
    filterVeg.setTextColor(R.color.black)
    filterNonveg.backgroundTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(R.color.white)
    filterNonveg.setTextColor(R.color.black)
    when(view?.id) {
        R.id.filter_both -> {
            filterBoth.backgroundTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(R.color.black)
            filterBoth.setTextColor(R.color.white)
        }
        R.id.filter_veg -> {
            filterVeg.backgroundTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(R.color.black)
            filterVeg.setTextColor(R.color.white)
        }
        R.id.filter_nonveg -> {
            filterNonveg.backgroundTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(R.color.black)
            filterNonveg.setTextColor(R.color.white)
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
Can I somehow use RadioButton and RadioGroup for this functionality? How to set radiobutton view to a custom view for both checked and unchecked state?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55139080/12148482

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```kotlin
val filterButtons = listOf(filterBoth, filterVeg, filterNonveg)
filterButtons.forEach { btn ->
    btn.setOnClickListener {
        filterButtons.forEach {
            val bgColor = if(it == btn) R.color.black else R.color.white
            val textColor = if(it == btn) R.color.white else R.color.black
            it.backgroundTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(bgColor)
            it.setTextColor(textColor)
        }
    }
}
```

> What to do if the number of categories is not fixed?

Just add more buttons in the `filterButtons` list and everything else remains the same.

Comment: Thanks for the code.
On further exploration, can I set custom view in radio button as it would achieve the same objective

Comment: That seems to be a completely different question. You should post it as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`MaterialToggleButtonGroup`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButtonToggleGroup) with `singleSelection` set to true.  That way you can theme them as usual, all the usual button states (like hover) will look right, they'll automatically uncheck if another is checked, and they'll work better with accessibility services.

You can use `addOnButtonCheckedListener` on the group layout to handle one of the buttons being selected.

Material Design docs here too: https://material.io/components/buttons/android#toggle-button